# SSD drives with SAS Interface

Tags: storage, ssd, scsi

Why there aren't any SSD with SAS interface? Are there any technological limitations or it is simply because manufacturers haven't produced one yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Zeus IOPS SSD (used by Oracle storage and others) uses SAS interfaces at 3G or 6G.

http://www.stec-inc.com/product/zeusiops.php

In addition, the Sandisk/Pliant line has SAS 6G interfaces.

http://www.sandisk.com/business/industries/enterprise/

Other options are listed here: http://www.storagesearch.com/ssd-sas.html

Comment: I'm guessing that answers the question then...

Answer (score 2):

There are, HP have them for some of their mid/high-end SAN boxes for instance.

That said I believe there will be less need for SAS SSD as the main benefit SAS brings over SATA is that of dealing with the longer and more diverse queues seen in multiuser environments. SSDs are inherently better at dealing with random workloads than regular disks; look at the performance differentials between magnetic and flash disks when used in sequential and random operations, essentially SSDs slow down less than regular disks as a percentage of their sequential performance.

Comment: SAS also allows for dual-ported drives, which helps when implementing controller level redundancy. You can get SAS interposers for SATA disks, but not all environments allow for their user.

Comment: SATA can be dual ported too though.

Answer (score 1):

SATA drives are supposedly upward compatible for use in SAS bays. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_attached_SCSI).